# The Bootstrap drop down menu in navigation bar working on content pages with no data, but if i add some data, it doesn't work anymore

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

1. I am using a master page and creating content pages from it for my website. Trying to show a drop-down menu in the navigation bar, but not working when I add data into the context placeholder.
2. I have been trying to do this for a long time and tried to use the drop down menu on click instaed of hover, but that doens't work too.

```html
<!--this is the masters page-->
    <style>
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

<!--the body part-->
 <div class="auto-style3 navbar">
  <a href="default.aspx">Home</a>
  <a href="#cars.aspx">Vehicles</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Finance 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">About Finance</a>
      <a href="#">Apply For Finance</a>
 
    </div>
  </div> 
                 <a href="Reviews.aspx"> Reviews</a>
                 <a href="Faq.aspx"> FAQ</a>
                 <a href="ContactUs.aspx"> Contact Us</a>
                 <a href="AboutUs.aspx"> About Us</a>
</div>

<!--working in a plain content page (with no data)-->
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HomeMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="BootstrapDemo.WebForm4" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<!--But not in another content page with data-->
 <div class="container">
    <h1 style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold; font-family: Calibri; font-size: xx-large">About Trend Motors:</h1>
<p>    <span>Trend motors was started by Bhuvnesh in 2016 who’s dream is to supply quality cars at competitive prices. He set about gathering like minded people to form a team of dedicated and experienced co-workers to help him on his mission. So the correct mix of people, experience, and huge industry knowledge now forms the tight compact team that is Trend Motors.</span></p>

    <p><span>Selling good cars at better prices throughout New Zealand from the North cape to bluff our experienced team can help you all the way, from the first enquiry to the delivery of the vehicle. We pride ourselves on stocking a wide range of vehicles from the top end &nbsp;to the family cars and the cutest fuel efficient cars. We will always have a selection and a car for you.</span></p>
    <br />
      <h2 style="font-size: xx-large; font-family: Calibri; font-weight: bold; color: #FF0000"> How to Find Us?</h2>
      <div id="map_populate" style="width:100%; height:500px; border: 5px solid #5E5454;">
          </div>
 </div>
```